Anonymous in react native while profiling release builds
I'm currently using the React Native Release Profiler (https://github.com/margelo/react-native-release-profiler) to profile the release build of my React Native application. However, I'm encountering an issue where all components in the profiler output are shown as "anonymous".
Here's an example of my setup:
App.tsx
import { Component1 } from './src/component-1/Component1';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { startProfiling, stopProfiling } from 'react-native-release-profiler';

const App = () => {
  console.log('-----------Component1', Component1.displayName);
  startProfiling();

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Component1 />
      <Button
        title={'Stop'}
        onPress={() => {
          stopProfiling(true);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;

Component1.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

const Component1 = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ width: 400, backgroundColor: 'pink', height: 200 }}>
      <Text>{'component-1'}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
Component1.displayName = 'Component1';
export { Component1 };

Despite setting the displayName property for each component, the React Native Release Profiler still shows all components as "anonymous" in the profiler output.
Ideally it should have shown displayName of component.
This is the result I am getting on speed scope
